# Meta tags usages in HTML header

Tags: html

There are so many meta tags used while creating a website, can anyone explain why they're required and their usage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Meta tags are HTML `<meta>` elements that provide metadata about your page.  The most common ones are used to specify the page's **description** and **keywords** that decribe its content. Both of these can be used by search engines to help index your page, although description has become more important than keywords.

```
<meta name="description" content="My page about awesome animals" />
<meta name="keywords" content="unicorns, dugongs, marmosets" />
```

Another other use for meta tags is to emulate the behaviour of an HTTP response header, for example to set a page's caching policy:

```
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

The HTML spec doesn't define a standard set of properties for meta tags, but there's a set of *de facto* tags that are generally accepted and implemented by browsers.  Some of the most common ones are listed here - [Useful HTML Meta Tags](http://www.i18nguy.com/markup/metatags.html) - with example usages.

Comment: Keywords has been worthless since the 90s. It was too often used to spam. Caching *needs* to be handled with real HTTP headers, meta tags are insufficient.

Comment: @David in some cases meta keywords can be useful, say if need you index your company's web content with something like a Google Search Appliance, but yes they've been pretty useless for at least the last few years.  For caching, agree it's better handled server-side, but if you've only got access to the HTML template it can be a useful kludge.

Comment: @Deepika HTTP caching is quite a big subject in itself, recommend posting a new question to get the best response

Answer (score 1):

The ones you want to use are title (not really a meta tag) and description. Keywords is obsolete these days.

Here's a list of some popular ones: http://www.metatags.org/all_metatags

Many of those are useless though, and have no support such as copyright and web_author.

Answer (score 0):

<del>W3Schools or other HTML reference sites are your best friends when you're making a HTML homepage! :D
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp</del>
Meta tag is used to indicate the 'metadata' of a website, such as encoding, site keywords and descriptions (which is used by search engine), author of website, or the language used.
<del>If you're lazy, then you may only add about encoding, such as  `<meta charset='utf-8'/>`</del>

EDIT : Sorry.. I didn't know about that...

Comment: That page fails to explain any of the possible values, so it doesn't answer the question. W3Schools is [best avoided](http://w3fools.com) anyway. There is nothing lazy about only specifying the encoding, you shouldn't even need to do that (it is a job for HTTP headers) except for a security problem in old MSIE.

Comment: Sorry... :( I didn't know that W3C and W3School is unrelated and W3School has many problems...